# Eliminate default HTML checkboxes, replace with CSS instead

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm pretty new at this, so I hope I'm asking this question correctly. I am so close to getting this I can taste it!! My goal is to eliminate the boring default checkboxes so that you can only see the CSS buttons.

Position: Absolute; gets rid of all the middle inputs which is good, however the first and last one still remain for seemingly no reason (no matter how many I have?). The first checkbox looks like it's floating left for some reason, and the last checkbox is just hanging out. I can push the last checkbox off the screen if I need to, but the first one still remains and that doesn't seem like it would be a good fix anyway.
Any help?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="my.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="maindiv">
    <input type="checkbox" id="a" value="1"><label for="a">Every</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="b" value="1"><label for="b">Good</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c" value="1"><label for="c">Boy</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="d" value="1"><label for="d">Deserves</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="e" value="1"><label for="e">Fudge</label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#maindiv {
}
input[type=checkbox] + label {
    text-align: center;
    background: yellow;
    color: black;
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background: orange;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label + input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Why not just set `display: none;` on the checkboxes (assuming you want them to all disappear)?

Comment: I'm humbled by your quick, easy, and sorta embarrassing answer! haha thanks for this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp),

> The `<label>` element does not render as anything special for the user.
>   However, it provides a usability improvement for mouse users, because
>   if the user clicks on the text within the  element, it toggles
>   the control.

So just hide the checkboxes and it is all good.

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  display:none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TqW92/

Comment: Umm.. you guys are brilliant. At least compared to me. I'm pretty sure I've wasted about 5 hours on this now :|
That absolutely worked!!! haha

Comment: display: none is not advisible for accessibility.

Comment: Accessibility shouldn't be the developer's headache. If it's so important that a tiny part of the population (that isn't even the target consumer) can experience sites properly, there would've been css attributes for screen readers. This is like adapting bikes for the blind!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xNskB/3/

```
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  padding: 0.25em;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label:first-child {
  margin: 0;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  height: 1px; 
  width: 1px; 
  margin: -1px; 
  padding: 0; 
  border: 0; 
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background: orange;
}

<div id="maindiv">
  <input type="checkbox" id="a" value="1"><label for="a">Every</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="b" value="1"><label for="b">Good</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="c" value="1"><label for="c">Boy</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d" value="1"><label for="d">Deserves</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="e" value="1"><label for="e">Fudge</label>
</div>
```